# generate a random network as a reference for small-wroldness comparison with gephi

Tags: r, graph, graph-theory, gephi

I am trying to determine if my directed Graph G is a “small world”. The graph is created from my dataset which consists of 500 nodes, but only 60 nodes have edges (total of 150 edges).I believe to do so I need to compare the clustering coefficient and the average path length to a random graph R with the same amount of nodes and edges.

Q1: Gephi has an embedded "generate Random Graph" capability - what is the algorithm it uses?

Q2: should I just generate a graph R with 60 nodes and 150 edges, or with 500 nodes and 150 edges?

Q3: I found small differences between definitions of small-worldness test. The one I am using is taken from Humphries, M. D. and K. Gurney (2008). "Network ‘small-world-ness’: a quantitative method for determining canonical network equivalence." PloS one 3(4): e0002051. "The network G is said to be a small-world network if Lg≥Lr and Cg≫Cr" (L is average path length and C is global clustering coefficient). any insights on this definition?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please ask one thing at a time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [paper](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/uzzi/ftp/Uzzi_EuropeanManReview_2007.pdf) gives a better insight on empirically testing whether a graph is small world. Indeed you have to create a random graph to test your graph.

**Q1:** As one can see from the [code](https://github.com/cbartosiak/gephi-plugins/blob/complex-generators/ComplexGeneratorPlugin/src/org/gephi/io/complexgenerator/plugin/ErdosRenyiGnm.java) the Gnp, Gnm generators are based on Batagelj, Brandes, *Efficient Generation of Large Random Networks*, Sunbelt Conf. on Social Networks, 2004, available [here](http://algo.uni-konstanz.de/publications/bb-eglrn-05.pdf).

**Q2:** The way CC is defined takes into account the number of *triangles* and *connected triples*. This notion discards automatically all the isolated nodes (unless you computer the *average clustering coefficient* by averaging over the number of nodes. This is not what you want though.

The bottom line is that it shouldn't make any difference which graph to choose in your case

**Q3:** Check the paper in the introduction of my answer for a more intuitive definition and check